# Sumif or Sumproduct with criteria of not containing a specific decimal number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, sumproduct

I'm trying to add a summed value into C1. I have column A containing data records and column B containing amounts. I want to sum the data that does not contain ".6". I've used "<>" in sumif and sumproduct formulas a lot but something about the decimal is throwing it off.

It looks like this:

`Column A    Column B
 1.00          $10
 15.00         $15
 14.00         $20
 2.11          $5
 12.60041      $10
 5.12          $10
 3.60056       $20`

Formulas I've tried are

`=SUMIF(A2:A10,"<>*.6*",B2:B10)`

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10<>"*.6*")*B2:B10)`

and variations of these with &"*"& like:

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10<>"*"&".6"&"*")*B2:B10)`

These formulas are just summing all my records.
I've also tried changing column format to Text instead of general or number

My goal is to sum the amounts in column B when the Record in Column A does NOT contain ".6"

Thank you so much for the help. This seems like a simple problem but i suspect the decimal is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SUMPRODUCT doesn't accept wildcards. You could use something like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND(".6",A2:A8)))),B2:B8)
```